# Is it legal to display third-party logos as part of "As featured in" on sites/printed ads without their consent?

Tags: logo, copyright, legal, marketing, trademark

Have seen more companies include logos of media outlets on their site/printed marketing material as part of the "As featured in" section.

Is it legal to do this without the companies' consent (especially on printed material)?

Comment: This is a question about law, not graphic design. And it's not even an answerable question—as go-meek's answer points out, different companies have different terms of use, and different jurisdictions have different laws broadening, restricting, and otherwise interacting with those terms. The only way to get a proper answer is to ask a lawyer and restrict the question to using a specific company’s logo in a specific situation.

Comment: While it is true this is about law. Having a good overview of how it works is good to know, essential even, for graphics designers. The fact that each copyright holder can impose an arbitrary requirement is central to the entire point of your industry. So i would not want to see this post closed.

Answer (score 5):

**Each company or organization has their own terms about this.**

So you might want to read them for each logo before adding them on your website or marketing material.

For example, you cannot add a badge or a logo that could mislead your visitors in thinking you're part of some association when you're not. The permission to use that logo comes with the membership.

Sometimes you need to get the file approved before printing it.

**Examples:**

> 1. Advertising, Promotional, and Sales Materials: *Only Apple and its authorized resellers and licensees may use the Apple Logo in
>      advertising, promotional, and sales materials*. Such authorized parties
>      may use the Apple Logo only as specified in their agreement with Apple
>      and any associated Guidelines and such use must always be in
>      conjunction with the appropriate terms that define the relationship
>      authorized by their contract with Apple. [...]
>
> http://www.apple.com/legal/intellectual-property/guidelinesfor3rdparties.html

http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/blog/affiliate-logo-guidelines-and-art.html

https://developer.apple.com/softwarelicensing/agreements/pdf/mac_logo_license_agreement.pdf

> We will need as much information as possible in order to consider your
>   request. You will need to fill in an online request form and provide
>   design concepts.
>
> If we are able to grant permission to use or assets, is likely that we
>   will require you to enter into a trademark license agreement with the
>   BBC, which sets out what you are permitted to do (duration of use,
>   territory, etc.)
>
> http://www.bbc.co.uk/branding/logo_use

Comment: Great answer! Thanks for the links, I have been wondering something like it a while back.