# Popular brands logos to use in a template / copyright issue?

Tags: copyright

I've seen many templates sold on Themeforest and other similar marketplaces use popular brands logos (e.g. Apple, Samsung, Google, etc.) in 'Our clients" sections.

I also sell templates on different marketplaces, and I wonder if using such brands would be an issue from the copyright point of view? If I am allowed to use them in the preview, may I also include them in the download package?

Comment: Related: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/62884/is-it-legal-to-display-third-party-logos-as-part-of-as-featured-in-on-sites-pr/62889#62889