# Is the Bluetooth logo a registered symbol?

Tags: legal, symbols, product-design

I'd like to use a Bluetooth symbol which will be a visible part of my product for sale.

Can I legally use this graphic?

[image]

Comment: What part of your product? Are you going to use it just to indicate the product has bluetooth / is compatible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it legal to display third-party logos as part of "As featured in" on sites/printed ads without their consent?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/62884/is-it-legal-to-display-third-party-logos-as-part-of-as-featured-in-on-sites-pr)

Comment: @Luciano this bluethoot sign will be cut out in plastic and permanently attached to the product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. It is a "registered symbol". However....

The Bluetooth symbol is *specifically designed* to be included on product packaging and marketing materials in order to indicate to the consumer that the item is "Bluetooth aware" or capable.

With this in mind, of course you can use the symbol on packaging for your product. Merely ensure you stick to the usage guidelines.

**[Here is a PDF LINK](http://tkhf.adaxas.net/cd1/bluetooth%20brandbook_E.pdf)** to the **Bluetooth "Brand Book"** which details usage and permissible display.

Note that you are *not* permitted to use the Bluetooth symbol in something like a "logo". Rather, merely as an indicator your product/service is compatible with Bluetooth devices.

Comment: Thanks Scott. In my case this symbol will be cut out in plastic or steal and permanently attached to my product, as a part of a design / look.

Comment: Hmm.. not sure I'd permanently work it into the actual product. But, well, you've seen it I haven't :)

Comment: Let me put it this way - imagine matches which are put in this 'B' symbol of Bluetooth. They actually create this symbol only. And my furniture pieces when put together create this 'B' symbol. Does it still count as trademark use?

Comment: I'm **not** an attorney. If the sole or primary purpose of something is to *create* the symbol, then I don't know. You'd need to discuss this with a trademark/patent attorney. If one of the primary selling point s**is** the symbol, then that may be too much - similar to how stock images can't be used on cups/t-shirts/mousepads etc. If the thing that would actually sell the product is copyrighted to another, I don't know that you can then freely sell such an item. Again, I am **not** an attorney though.